# Split WordPress Latest Posts in Multiple Columns and Rows with one single loop

Tags: posts, loop

I have this layout I am trying to implement - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cP831xAM1F5CT3HEmedCBkINwiCC18Rb/view

And I have created a news template, but I need to get the posts to display like my example where the first bootstrap row displays 3 posts then beneath that it displays 4 posts.

Is this possible, I cant seem to find the relevant information for me to achieve this.

Really hoping someone can point me in the right direction, on how I would code my template for this layout.

Many Thanks

Here is my current code

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <?php
        while ( have_posts() ) {
            the_post(); 

            $class = 'col-md-4';

            if( $counter < 3 ) {
                $class = 'col-md-3';
            }

            ?>
            <div class="col-12 <?php echo $class; ?>">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail(', '); ?>
                <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="Read more"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
            </div> <!-- .col-12 -->
            <?php

            $counter++;

        } // end while
    ?>
    </div><!-- .row -->
</div><!-- .container -->
```

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by using a counter then updating the class according to your needs. The code below will create a variable `$counter` and assign it to `0` if posts exist. By default a `'col-md-4'` is bound to `$class`, if the `$counter` is less than `3` `$class` will be updated to `'col-md-3'` (making it fill 4 columns instead of 3). Then we output the html including the stored class. Finally, the `$counter` is incremented ready for the next post item.

```
<?php 
if ( have_posts() ) {
    $counter = 0;

    ?>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <?php
            while ( have_posts() ) {
                the_post(); 

                $class = 'col-md-4';

                if( $counter < 3 ) {
                    $class = 'col-md-3';
                }

                ?>
                <div class="col-12 <?php echo $class; ?>">
                    <?php // content etc here ?>
                </div> <!-- .col-12 -->
                <?php

                $counter++;

            } // end while
        ?>
        </div><!-- .row -->
    </div><!-- .container -->
<?php } else { // end if ?>
    <p>There are no posts to display</p>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, when I try and add your code I get a syntax error?

Comment: It might be this line? - <?php } // end if ?>

Comment: I have not tested the code, can you give me the exact error you're getting?

Comment: I forgot a reopening `<?php` tag after the `<div class="row">`

Comment: Many thanks, but when I add the code to my template, I just get a blank page and no posts show?

Comment: Because the code that I've provided doesn't output any content can you see `<?php // content etc here ?>` That is where you can add everything you need in that section. e.g if you add `<?php the_title('<h2>', '</h2>') ;?>` this will output the title of each post

Comment: I am trying to past the code I have added as I just realised like you said I did not add any content! How do I past code here?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "How do I paste code here?"

Comment: I think I understand, I will give it a go, I meant how do I submit here the code I have, as it does not let me because of too many characters, your help is much appreciated :)

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, you can add the code you have here by editing your original question and adding it there

Comment: When I add in the title tag and thumbnail tag, still nothing displays?

Comment: This is my code - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WAamLFstKOL6UPMc7JLXV4y-5nlQoCYY

Comment: Please add your code to the description of your question. Also update your code to represent my latest edit to establish whether there are actually posts to display.

Comment: That's what I said earlier when I paste code into my comment it says I have used all the characters allowed to post a comment?

Comment: I have now updated my original message with code, thanks again.

Comment: In you original image of code that you attached to google drive you where using this code inside what appears to be a page template `/* Template Name: News */ `. Have you tried the code I've provided in index.php? Have you looked at [the loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) and [page templates](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/) in the wp docs?

Comment: I have updated the page template code - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1cZhFbxy6BxUXV-k214g4G-0WoSFzzX3m - I have created a News page and set the template to - News, but still no posts showing?

Comment: You are missing the point, you have created a page template, then set a page to have a template "News" but you are not telling wp that you want to display your posts on this page. Update your code represent my last edit (including the `else`) it will say "There are no posts to display". You can either update the code to use `WP_Query` or set the News page to your posts page in admin settings see [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/246823/custom-page-template)

Answer (score 0):

try to take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38304093/wordpress-blog-first-row-2-column-second-and-continuing-rows-3-columns

Is it similar to what you want to achieve?

Comment: More or less, but I need to show first 3 latest posts on one row with 3 columns, then beneath that other latest posts within a 4 column row.